# Web Service Retry Java

Tags: java, web

I have a Java web app A that sends Pojo's to anothet web app B. I want to create a mechanism that retries the sending of the Pojos from A to B if B is down. The way B's api is configured in A is via Spring with B's jars in A's classpath. I have made a stab at it but the retry is not working. Can anyone tell me if I'm going in the right direction?

What is wrong here is that my code first executes, then rightly throws an exception. The exception is caught in the catch block. The catch block re-calls callB()  which rightly throws an exception again but then my retry code goes into non source-file exception handling code and stops.

EDIT: I cannot use jcabi-aspects because it is not supported in Gradle.

```
public Object getB(Object request){

    if (bClient != null) {
      int retryCount = 0;
      try {
        return callB(request);
      } catch (Exception e) {

        if (++retryCount > 3) {
           return null;
        }
        return callB(request);
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

      private Object callB(Object request){
        return bClient.callServiceB(request);
      }
```

Comment: "Is not working" is not a valid problem description. Post actual details.

Comment: I don't see any code related to WS programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write java client code for retry call to Java webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286941/how-to-write-java-client-code-for-retry-call-to-java-webservice)

Comment: @robermann - yes, I'm trying that method in parallel. I dont know how to add the jcabi-aspects plugin in Gradle - any ideas? Here is it in Maven:

Comment: <project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcabi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>ajc</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want code to *repeatedly* do something *until* it is successful,  consider writing the control logic as a loop. You will find this makes it easy for you to change the number of retries before the code should give up.