# Run method inside a method in java

Tags: java

I'm sending more than 1 request to a web service, below there is an example of that requests. Its important for my application to get the answer from the web service so if there is an exception application will try couple of times to get the answer.

Because of that getting something simple like 
`deviceList  = serviceAdapter.getDevices();` is turn into below code.

```
boolean flag = true;
int counter = 1;
List<Device> deviceList = null;

while (flag) {
   try {
        deviceList  = serviceAdapter.getDevices(); 
        flag = false;
   } catch (Exception e) {
           try {
                if (counter == 5) {
                    System.out.println("Timeout Occured!");
                    flag = false;
                } else {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * counter);
                    counter++;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            }
    }
}
```

And in my application i have lots of requests which means there will be more ugly codes. Is there a way where i will call my request methods as parameter for another method something like this:

```
deviceList = wrapperMethod(serviceAdapter.getDevices());
```

Problem is there will be different type of requests, so they will return different type objects (list,array,string,int) and their paramaters will change. Is there a suitable solution in java for this problem?

Comment: Did you consider inheritance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write java client code for retry call to Java webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286941/how-to-write-java-client-code-for-retry-call-to-java-webservice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `Supplier<T>` to the `wrapperMethod`:

```
public static <T> T wrapperMethod (Supplier<T> supp) {
    boolean flag = true;
    int counter = 1;
    T value = null;

    while (flag) {
       try {
            value = supp.get(); 
            flag = false;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           try {
                if (counter == 5) {
                    System.out.println("Timeout Occured!");
                    flag = false;
                } else {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 * counter);
                    counter++;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it with:

```
List<Device> deviceList = wrapperMethod (() -> serviceAdapter.getDevices());
```

I'm afraid, though, that it will limit the methods you call within the lambda expression to throw only `RuntimeException`s.

Comment: This is the exact solution for my problem. I've just changed Supplier with Callable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@RetryOnFailure` annotation from [jcabi-aspects](https://aspects.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.22.6/com/jcabi/aspects/RetryOnFailure.html)

Create a wrapper method then annotate it to enable auto retry upon Exception

As an example:

```
@RetryOnFailure(attempts = 5)
List<Device> retryWhenFailed(ServiceAdapter serviceAdapter) throws Exception {
    return serviceAdapter.getDevices();
}
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more of information, like an example ? I am intrigued!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some command implementation to execute some specific codes :

Here is a simple example of a command

```
interface Command{
    void run();
}
```

And a couple of implementations :

```
class SayHello implements Command{
    @Override
    public void run() {System.out.println("Hello World");}
}

class KillMe implements Command{
    public void run() { throw new RuntimeException();};
}
```

All we have to do to execute those method is to receive an instance of `Command` and run the method :

```
public static void execCommand(Command cmd) {
    cmd.run();
}
```

And to use this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    execCommand(new SayHello());
    execCommand(new KillMe());
}
```

> Hello World
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException

It also accepts lambda expression :

```
execCommand(() -> System.out.println("Say goodbye"));
```

And method reference :

```
public class Test{
    public static void testMe() {
        System.out.println("I work");
    }
}

execCommand(Test::testMe);
```

Note that I didn't specify that this could throw `Exception` so I am limited to unchecked exception like `RuntimeException` but of course `void run() throws Exception` could be a solution. That way you can do what ever you want.

Full example (with exceptions) :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            execCommand(new SayHello());
            execCommand(() -> System.out.println("Say goodbye"));
            execCommand(Test::testMe);
            execCommand(new KillMe());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void testMe() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("I work");
    }

    public static void execCommand(Command cmd) throws Exception {
        cmd.run();
    }
}

interface Command{
    void run() throws Exception;
}

class SayHello implements Command{
    @Override
    public void run() {System.out.println("Hello World");}
}

class KillMe implements Command{
    public void run() { throw new RuntimeException();};
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World  
Say goodbye  
I work  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException  
    at main.KillMe.run(Test.java:39)  
    at main.Test.execCommand(Test.java:25)
    at main.Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses Generics to be able to handle different Object with most of the same code and a Runnable to execute the fetching.

With this solution, you would need only to write the different adapters extending from `ServiceAdapter<T extends Fetchable>` to implement the logic to fetch the data for each different class (which would have to implement `Fetchable`).

Define an interface that abtracts the objects that can be fetched by the different services.

```
package so50488682;

public interface Fetchable {

}
```

The ojbect that are to be retrieved implement this interface so you can use the same code for different classes.

```
package so50488682;

public class Device implements Fetchable{
    private String  id;

    public Device(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "I am device " + id;
    }

}
```

Define an abstract `ServiceAdapter` that the different service adapters will extend to implement the logic for each kind of object to be retrieved. We add `throws Exception` to the get() method so this method cand just delegate the exception handling to the `FetcherService` and decide if it should retry or fail.

```
package so50488682;

import java.util.List;

public abstract class ServiceAdapter<T extends Fetchable> {

    public abstract List<T> get() throws Exception;
}
```

This is an example of an implementation done to get objects of class Device.

```
package so50488682;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DeviceServiceAdapter extends ServiceAdapter<Device>{

    @Override
    public List<Device> get() throws Exception{

        List<Device> rtn = new ArrayList<>();

        // fetch the data and put it into rtn, this is a mock
        Device d = new Device("1");
        rtn.add(d);
        d = new Device("2");
        rtn.add(d);
        d = new Device("3");
        rtn.add(d);
        //

        return rtn;
    }

}
```

Finally this is a generic solution to run the different service adapters.

```
public class FetcherService<T extends Fetchable> implements Runnable{

    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    ServiceAdapter<T> serviceAdapter;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        boolean flag = true;
        int counter = 1;

        while (flag) {
           try {
                result  = serviceAdapter.get(); 
                flag = false;
           } catch (Exception e) {
                   try {
                        if (counter == 5) {
                            System.out.println("Timeout Occured!");
                            flag = false;
                        } else {
                            Thread.sleep(1000 * counter);
                            counter++;
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Got Interrupted in sleep", e);
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<T> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<T> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public void setAdapter(ServiceAdapter<T> adapter) {
        this.serviceAdapter = adapter;
    }

}
```

From the main or calling program it work like this:

```
package so50488682;

import java.util.List;

public class SO50488682 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            DeviceServiceAdapter deviceServiceAdapter = new DeviceServiceAdapter();


            FetcherService<Device> deviceFetcherService = new FetcherService<>();
            deviceFetcherService.setAdapter(deviceServiceAdapter);
            deviceFetcherService.run();
            List<Device> devices = deviceFetcherService.getResult();

            for(Device device : devices) {
                System.out.println(device.toString());
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception after retrying a couple of times");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```